# requestImageDataForAsset is failed, when we request for PHAsset in iPhone sdk?

Tags: ios, phasset, photosframework

I am using the **photos framework** on **iOS9.2** and we requesting the image data for the **PHAsset** using **requestImageDataForAsset** method, Most of the time it works, but some time its **imageData** is nil, in case of when we request for **large video duration Asset**, and result dictionary contains all key value pairs that comes for every PHAsset.

Here's some code where I was request for imageData by using requestImageDataForAsset, but i never get the imageData anyway.

```
@autoreleasepool {
        __block NSData *data = nil;
        dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        PHImageRequestOptions* options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
        options.synchronous = YES;
        options.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;
        options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
        options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;

        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:assest options:options resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {
            data = imageData;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
        }];

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things I notice:

1. Why are you using a semaphore to block? You set set synchronous property of `PHImageRequestOptions` to `YES`, which should be sufficient for a non async (blocking) request.
2. The `requestImageDataForAsset` method of PHImageManager returns file mapped `NSData` objects. These are limited to about 1GB in size. If you call requestImageDataForAsset for large video assets, the `NSData` object can't be created and you will get a nil object as return. To request the data for videos, please have a look at `requestExportSessionForVideo`.